# How to access Ganache hosted on docker container from host OS?

Tags: docker, macos, ganache

I'm using cli version of ganache on ubuntu docker container, and need to access it from my host OS, ie. macos, how can i change the RPC url of ganache, from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

simply run, ganache -h `<address>`
ie. `ganache -h 0.0.0.0`